# Best way to get handle on the Ticks properties

Tags: plotting, ticks, plot-themes, frame

There are a lot of questions already on `Ticks`. However I did not find a better way to handle ticks place, size etc.

I have a simple example where I want have some handle on the ticks position and size. I found the undocumented functionality `` Charting`ScaledTicks `` from some of the previous questions in this forum which I think gives a great handle to tick-size. But when it comes to choosing the Major/Minor tick position I could not so far use it. And the problem is I do not know where I will get more information on this (apart from typing `` ?Charting`ScaledTicks ``).

Let’s take the following example where I want to set my Major ticks on even-places like `600, 800, ...` etc.

```
ListLinePlot[
  Table[{x, x}, {x, 500, 2000, 100}],
  Frame -> True,
  FrameStyle -> BlackFrame,
  FrameTicks -> {
    {Charting`ScaledTicks[{Identity, Identity}, TicksLength -> {.05, .02}], None},
    {Charting`ScaledTicks[{Identity, Identity}, TicksLength -> {.05, .02}][400, 2000, 8], None}
  }
]
```

After playing a bit, I am able to show the Major ticks on x-axis appearing on even-100-places, the minor ticks are gone. I am sure that I am missing something for the minor ticks in the `` Charting`ScaledTicks `` options but I dont know what should I do to make them reappear.

Here is an example where y-axis is automatically taking Major ticks, in the x-axis I try to force Major ticks appear at even-hundred places.

**How do I set position and size of Major ticks?**

Comment: Sorry found it. `ChartingScaledTicks[{Identity,Identity},TicksLength->{.05,.02}][400,2000,{8,5}]`.

Comment: It would be great if you could expand your comment to a self-answer with some explanation of the usage you found.

Comment: Boogeyman, you can get additional information on the syntax and resulting behavior of these functions by using `PrintDefinition` from the `GeneralUtilities` package within Mathematica. Searching those two terms on this site should lend you enough information to explore the definitions you want—any definition (to my understanding!).

Answer (score 2):

The way it can be done as follows

```
ListLinePlot[
  Table[{x, x},{x, 500, 2000, 100}],
  Frame->True,
  FrameTicks -> {
    {Charting`ScaledTicks[{Identity, Identity}, TicksLength -> {.05, .02}], None},
    {Charting`ScaledTicks[{Identity, Identity}, TicksLength -> {.05, .02}][400, 2000, {8, 5}], None}
  }
]
```

First of all, through  `TicksLength ->{0.05,0.02}` one can control the size of Major and Minor ticks.
Secondly the position for Major ticks can be controlled through (NdivM below),

```
Charting`ScaledTicks[{Identity, Identity}, TicksLength -> {.05, .02}][min, max, {NdivM, Ndivm}]
```

There one has to also keep `Ndivm` for Minor ticks.
In the above example I chose `min=400, max=2000, NdivM=8, Ndivm=5`.

Thanks to @CA Trevillian  now I know how to see the undocumented definition of such functionalities and all the possibilities it can do. For example for this case one can do

```
 Needs["GeneralUtilities`"];
 PrintDefinitions[Charting`ScaledTicks]
```

and can see everything about this function.

Comment: Can you explain the meaning behind your naming of `NdivM` and `Ndivm`? Find any way to easily have ticks labels of the values they mark, too?